# ICallbackEventHandler does not work in a WebControl

Tags: javascript, development

I've been trying to implement ICallbackEventHandler in a WebControl. I was able to do it easily in a normal Asp page. Could you please tell me what is the issue with the following code?

HTML Code:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <web:CustomC ID="Custom1" runat="server" />
            <br />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

C#:

```
namespace CustomControls
{
    [DefaultProperty("Text")]
    [ToolboxData("<{0}:CustomC runat=server></{0}:CustomC>")]
    public class CustomC : WebControl, System.Web.UI.ICallbackEventHandler
    {
        [Bindable(true)]
        [Category("Appearance")]
        [DefaultValue("")]
        [Localizable(true)]
        public string Text
        {
            get
            {
                String s = (String)ViewState["Text"];
                return ((s == null) ? String.Empty : s);
            }

            set
            {
                ViewState["Text"] = value;
            }
        }
        protected string tempvar;
        protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output)
        {
            output.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Div);
            output.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Id, this.ClientID + "_t");
            output.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Label);
            output.Write("Enter: ");
            output.RenderEndTag();
            output.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Type, "button");
            output.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Id, this.ClientID + "_i");
            output.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Value, "Click Me");
            output.AddAttribute("OnClick", "CallServer('test','');");
            output.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Input);
            output.RenderEndTag();
            output.RenderEndTag();
        }

        protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
        {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
                typeof(Page),
                "HandleResult",
                "function HandleResult(arg) {" +
                "var lbl_id = this.ClientID + '_t'; var lbl = document.getElementById(lbl_id);" +
                lbl.innerHTML = arg;" +
            "}", true);

            ClientScriptManager cm = Page.ClientScript;
            string cbReference = cm.GetCallbackEventReference(this, "arg", "HandleResult", "context");
            string cbScript = "function CallServer(arg, context){" + cbReference + ";}";
            cm.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "CallServer", cbScript, true);

        }

        public void RaiseCallbackEvent(string eventArgument)
        {
            tempvar= eventArgument;
        }

        public string GetCallbackResult()
        {
            return "Valid Data is:" + tempvar ;
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: Does your control render properly in SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

Sample test demo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace TestWeb.WebControls
{
    [DefaultProperty("Text")]
    [ToolboxData("<{0}:WebCustomC runat=server></{0}:WebCustomC>")]
    public class WebCustomC : WebControl, ICallbackEventHandler
    {
        [Bindable(true)]
        [Category("Appearance")]
        [DefaultValue("")]
        [Localizable(true)]
        public string Text
        {
            get
            {
                String s = (String)ViewState["Text"];
                return ((s == null) ? String.Empty : s);
            }

            set
            {
                ViewState["Text"] = value;
            }
        }

        protected string tempvar;
        protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output)
        {
            output.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Div);
            output.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Id, this.ClientID + "_t");
            output.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Label);
            output.Write("Enter: ");
            output.RenderEndTag();
            output.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Type, "button");
            output.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Id, this.ClientID + "_i");
            output.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Value, "Click Me");
            output.AddAttribute("OnClick", "CallServer('test','');");
            output.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Input);
            output.RenderEndTag();
            output.RenderEndTag();
        }

        protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
        {
            ClientScriptManager scriptManager = Page.ClientScript;

            String cbReference = scriptManager.GetCallbackEventReference(this, "returnValue", "GetResult", "context");

            String callbackScript = "function CallServer(returnValue, context) {" + cbReference + "; } function GetResult(returnValue, context) {alert(returnValue)}";

            scriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "CallServer", callbackScript, true);

            if (Page.IsCallback)
            {
                ////IF any operation do it here.
            }

        }

        private string returnValue;
        public string GetCallbackResult()
        {
            return returnValue;
        }

        public void RaiseCallbackEvent(string eventArgument)
        {
            returnValue = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TestPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestWeb.TestPage" %>

<%--<%@ Register Src="~/UserControls/CustomC.ascx" TagName="CustomC" TagPrefix="web"%>--%>
<%@ Register Namespace="TestWeb.WebControls" TagPrefix="web" Assembly="TestWeb" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <web:WebCustomC ID="Custom1" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]